# Why is my wired connection not preferred over my wireless?

Tags: networking

When connected to a wire, the wire should be the preferred connection.  For some reason when I try to do DNS or connect to machines that are on the local wired LAN, the kernel is trying to use my hotspot instead.

What can I set to force the wired be the preferred connection?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Make script in the folder `/etc/network/if-up.d/` called script with execute `permissions 755`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0
# Adding additional routes on connection
route add default dev eth0
route add ...
route add ...
```

or

You can change metric.  `route add default dev wlan0 metric 20` When you change metric you default route to `eth0` will have less metric and traffic will go via `wless0`. When `eth0` is down you default route to `eth0` will be deleted from routing table and traffic will go via `wlan0`. After when you `eth0` is again up, default metric will be less then 20 on `wlan0` and traffic will again go to `eth0`.

Also you can edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and set metric permanent for interface.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
metric XXX
```